# parsing text with html tags

Tags: android, xml-parsing, saxparser, domparser

I have to parse an xml file from a  server;
I tried with DOm parser and Sax parser but I'm not able to parse html tags and it stops when it finds the first "<"

This is my parser class:

```
public class XMLParser {

    // constructor
    public XMLParser() {

    }


    public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
        String xml = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;

        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            in =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));


            StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer("");
             String line = "";
             String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");

             while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line );
                    sb.append(NL );
                    line=in.readLine();
                }
             in.close();

            xml = sb.toString();;

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return XML
        return xml;
    }

    public Document getDomElement(String xml){
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
                is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
                doc = db.parse(is); 

            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }

            return doc;
    }


     public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
         Node child;
         if( elem != null){
             if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
                 for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                     if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                         return child.getNodeValue();
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         return "";
     }

     /**
      * Getting node value
      * @param Element node
      * @param key string
      * */
     public String getValue(Element item, String str) {     
            NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
        return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML is not well-formed (e.g. contains  tags that aren't closing), neither of those parsers are going to work. You may end up having to parse by hand (e.g. by using regular expressions and the [Pattern](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class). If the HTML is well-formed, you should post what error you're receiving, and maybe a link to the page.

Comment: [link](http://mirsitelfi.comoj.com/test.php)
do you think this html is not well-formed!??

Comment: I'm no expert, but that looks like an XML document with an HTML header. Your boss should start by fixing the header (see http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ )

Answer (score 0):

You should use an HTML parser because most html content available on the web does not comply with XML spec.
In simple cases regular expressions are enough to do the trick, but in complex cases you might need an HTML parser.

Comment: i don"t have a chose i must do it with xmlparser !! :(

Comment: Then you are out of choices, because as I explained XML parsers are just unusable. By the way, why do you have to use an XML parser?

Comment: this a project and "the boss" asked me to do it with xml parser O.o